# How to remove padding from first and last row element properly in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been using bootstrap for quite a while now and I'm facing this problem for the first time. I really don't know how to do this. I have found many people suggesting to just remove `padding-left` on the `first-child` element and the last one. I also tried this way at first but then I realized that it couldn't work, since the `.col` class has the `box-sizing: border-box;` property which makes the div to have padding included in the width. (Which is obviously necessary if you want a clean layout using `width: 25%;`).

So, if you remove these padding on the left, the first and last div are going to be 15px larger, which breaks the layout... I want every col div to have exactly the same width, I want them to fit 100% of the row and have no padding left or right. Is there a class that I'm not aware of in bootstrap?

Is it possible while keeping the Bootstrap 3 templating system?

Code example:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finaly found a way around it by creating my own class, that I believe respect the way bootstrap made their layouting system. Here was the best and minimal way to do it:

CSS

```
.layout-no-gutter-around.is-4-columns > .col-md-3{
   margin: 0 5px;
 }

.layout-no-gutter-around.is-4-columns > .col-md-3:first-child{
   margin-left: 0;
   padding-left: 0;
   width: calc(25% - 15px);
}

.layout-no-gutter-around.is-4-columns > .col-md-3:last-child{
   margin-right: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
   width: calc(25% - 15px);
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="row layout-no-gutter-around is-4-colums">
   <div class="col-md-3"></div>
   <div class="col-md-3"></div>
   <div class="col-md-3"></div>
   <div class="col-md-3"></div>
 </div>
```

This way, I achieve exactly what I want, it's reusable and respect the Twitter's Bootstrap thinking (I believe). Thanks to Deja Vu who leaded me to the calc thiking, I believe it's a good way to achieve this. But you cannot put 15 margin left on the first child and right on the last child since that would still create a gutter around but using the margin.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to solve your problem but I have 2 ideas and maybe it will lead you to the solution.

1. #### Replace `padding`s with `margin`s

html

```
<div class="row" id="optionOne">
  <div class="col-md-3">first child</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">child</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">child</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">last child</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#optionOne > div:first-child {
    background-color: red; /* for display purposes only */
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
#optionOne > div:last-child {
    background-color: yellow; /* for display purposes only */
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Not sure if that would satisfy your *design* requirements.

2. #### recalc width

css

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #optionTwo > div:first-child {
        background-color: green; /* for display purposes only */
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    #optionTwo > div:last-child {
        background-color: grey; /* for display purposes only */
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
    #optionTwo > div:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
        background-color: blue; /* for display purposes only */
        width: calc(25% + 15px);
    }
}
```

The problem I faced was - in both cases last child falls onto the separate row:
[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f86e6n7v/1/).

Hope this will give you some food-for-thought.

Comment: hmm yeah I tought about 2 options, with the calc in css, I could probably apply 25% + 7.5px width to every div since I have to remove 30px total from the row. Good tought. Or maybe that if I use the flexbox CSS3 property it would work better, tho I'd kinda break the bootstrap float layout system hmmm. I tought about margin before but it didn't seemed to work properly, the last child was falling on another row... Good thinking tho

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment on Yann Chabot's post, but as an extension on it, I would recommend to use escape values. If you don't use this, Chrome recalculates the width to 10% instead of the correct width.

CSS

```
width: calc(~"25% - 15px");
```

Comment: Are you sure? I did this in the past and it seemed to work without the ~ sign?

Comment: It calculated my first child-element in the parent-element wrong. My first element always came out with a width of 10%, this fixed it for me. I finally had to tweak the code because I had a variable number of child-items, and I did not had to use the css width line anymore.


This did the trick for me:
`.layout-no-gutter-around.is-4-columns > .col-md-3 {
    padding: 0 6px;
}
.layout-no-gutter-around.is-4-columns > .col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1) {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.layout-no-gutter-around.is-4-columns > .col-md-3:nth-child(4n+4) {
    padding-right: 0;
}`

Comment: The above code is used in combination with the col-md-3 css (float & width)